# Counting the number of identical columns in sql and output it as a view

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to create an sql view where it needs to count the number of columns with the same content

for example

```
UID    person1_score    person2_score    person3_score    person4_score    person5_score    person6_score
1      1                1                1                1                2                2
```

the final output would be

```
UID    person1_score    person2_score    person3_score    person4_score    person5_score    person6_score    score_with_1    score_with_2
1      1                1                1                1                2                2                4               2
```

in the final output columns(score_with_1 and score_with_2) counted the number of people with a score "1" or "2" in that row

is there a way to make this happen?

Comment: im using phpmyadmin mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
CREATE VIEW view_Name AS
SELECT UID,    
       person1_score,
       person2_score,
       person3_score,
       person4_score,
       person5_score,
       person6_score 
       (SUM(CASE WHEN person1_score=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
        SUM(CASE WHEN person2_score=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
        SUM(CASE WHEN person3_score=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
        SUM(CASE WHEN person4_score=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
        SUM(CASE WHEN person5_score=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
        SUM(CASE WHEN person6_score=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
       AS score_with_1,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN person1_score=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
         SUM(CASE WHEN person2_score=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
         SUM(CASE WHEN person3_score=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
         SUM(CASE WHEN person4_score=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
         SUM(CASE WHEN person5_score=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
         SUM(CASE WHEN person6_score=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
      AS score_with_2
FROM Table t
```

Comment: if i want it to work for all rows in my table should i just remove the t.UID from WHERE statement and turn it into WHERE (person1_score=1 OR person2_score=1
 person2_score=1 OR person4_score=1)
 person5_score=1 OR person6_score=1)

Comment: i think you need something else. I will update my answer. could you please wait

Comment: So, it is always the case that score can be only 1 or 2? can it be 3 or 4 or x any time?